# How to store multiple rows in variable in PLSQL

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

i have a problem that store selected multiple rows in variable (or table variable i don't know about). I think it is possible to make it work. Here is my code

```
  SELECT RECIPIENT, COUNT (*) N_CNT
    FROM (SELECT RECIPIENT,
                 SERVICE_TYPE,
                 MPS_SWTCH_CD,
                 MPS_FTR_CD1
            FROM ABA_RM_INB_USAGE
           WHERE SERVICE_TYPE = 100
              OR SERVICE_TYPE = 0
             AND MPS_SWTCH_CD = 'T11'
             AND MPS_FTR_CD1 = 1033)
GROUP BY RECIPIENT
```

This query shows filtered rows and i need insert that rows into another table. Sorry for bad english by the way

Comment: What is your context to insert that selected data to another table? You may search for `GTT oracle` but why don't you just `INSERT INTO another_table(column1, column2) SELECT recipient, COUNT(*) FROM....`? And your query seem has syntax error, too.

Comment: Create a table of object with columns same as your query columns and store your query result using a variable to of your table type.

Comment: If you need to insert that result into another table, then just do so. No need for variables.

Comment: how ? can you give me some example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure, what you want to acchieve.

If you want to select from one table and insert into another, you can wrap an insert-statement around your select:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_RECIPIENT_COUNT
      SELECT RECIPIENT, COUNT (*) N_CNT
        FROM (SELECT RECIPIENT,
                     SERVICE_TYPE,
                     MPS_SWTCH_CD,
                     MPS_FTR_CD1
                FROM ABA_RM_INB_USAGE
               WHERE SERVICE_TYPE = 100
                  OR SERVICE_TYPE = 0
                 AND MPS_SWTCH_CD = 'T11'
                 AND MPS_FTR_CD1 = 1033)
    GROUP BY RECIPIENT;
```

If you want to do it within a plsql-script (or procedure..), you could define a type or loop through a cursor. Here's an example how to loop through a cursor and process the data:

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR cur
    IS
          SELECT RECIPIENT, COUNT (*) N_CNT
            FROM (SELECT RECIPIENT,
                         SERVICE_TYPE,
                         MPS_SWTCH_CD,
                         MPS_FTR_CD1
                    FROM ABA_RM_INB_USAGE
                   WHERE SERVICE_TYPE = 100
                      OR SERVICE_TYPE = 0
                     AND MPS_SWTCH_CD = 'T11'
                     AND MPS_FTR_CD1 = 1033)
        GROUP BY RECIPIENT;
BEGIN
    FOR item IN cur -- if you realy want to insert all results you should read about BULK-COLLECT and FORALL ;-)
    LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line('Result: ' || item.RECIPIENT || ', ' || item.N_CNT);
        INSERT INTO TABLE_RECIPIENT_COUNT
             VALUES (item.RECIPIENT, item.N_CNT);
    END LOOP loop_emp;
END;
```